# Is there support for SQL Server 2017 as App-V 5.1 Management Database?

Tags: appv

Is there support for SQL Server 2017 as App-V 5.1 Management Database? The documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-desktop-optimization-pack/appv-v5/app-v-51-supported-configurations doesn't say that SQL Server 2017 is supported, but the doc is pretty old.

I want to know if it's officially supported by Microsoft, and if it's not any ideas on whether it'll work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware it's not officially supported but has worked for me. I typically follow Rorymon's [blog](https://www.rorymon.com/blog/app-v-5-1-full-infrastructure-setup-part-1/) for these setups and it does give some information around what versions are supported. Also a good guide in general.

Comment: Microsoft is planning to support SQL 2017 with App-V 5.1, but there is no ETA as of today.